# Map a property to system column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, postgresql

Is there any chance to map property of a POCO object to a system column (using code-first)? This means that EF would not try to create the column by itself but rather count that it will already be there when `SELECT`-ing data from that table.

Suppose, for instance, that I had an Oracle or Postgres database and I wanted use respectively the `ora_rowscn` or the `xmin` system columns provided by the DBMS.

It seems to me as if EF is bound down to the bone to be working only with SQL Server.